# Return an integer literal from a Scheme function

Tags: scheme, racket

I've been reading about Scheme functions and have not seen one that simply returns an integer literal; likely because it would not be a very useful function. However, I am interested in trying to write a simple function in Scheme that takes arguments and just returns an integer. My function is:

```
(define (f x y) 1)
```

When I call the function with:

```
(f 4 5)
```

The result is:

```
4
5
```

Why would the function return both of the arguments rather than simply returning 1?

Comment: Could you provide the whole example? I just ran it and it returned `1` here: http://ideone.com/7PE0Mw

Comment: @lillemap Did you per chance forget the parenthesis and wrote `f 4 5` ?